# different import handling strategy for library and plugin dependency in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

Recently, I found out an interesting issue of sbt. It is very hard for me to describe it in several sentences, so here are several steps what I have done.

I have some kind of scala tasks for deployment. I published it into our local nexus repo, so several projects can use it. Here is the screenshot for internal nexus repo

[image]

Thus, I put it into the build.sbt file.

**"sbt.liquibase" % "**sbt-liquibase-deploy_2.10**" % "1.0-3"**

In this case, I have to specify **scala version 2.10**, If I reload to use

**"sbt.liquibase" % "**sbt-liquibase-deploy**" % "1.0-3"**

It failed on unresolved dependency, I am fine with that. However, after that, I thought that this task should be a plugin, so I can use it in the build.sbt file. I add setting sbtPlugin:true into task. The artifact changes from sbt-liquibase-deploy_2.10 to sbt-liquibase-deploy_2.10_0.13 after I published it. Basically, the sbt version is appended.

When I try to addPlugin to use these code

addSbtPlugin("sbt.liquibase" % "**sbt-liquibase-deploy_2.10**" % "1.0-3")

**It failed on unresolved dependency**

addSbtPlugin("sbt.liquibase" % "**sbt-liquibase-deploy_2.10_0.13**" % "1.0-3")

**It failed on unresolved dependency as well**

but if I dont use scala and sbt version at all, it is fine.

addSbtPlugin("sbt.liquibase" % "**sbt-liquibase-deploy**" % "1.0-3") //Successful

I have 3 questions.

1. why library dependency needs scala version while plugin dependency does not. It took several hours to fix it. It is not consistent.
2. when I use sbt publish task, the scala version and sbt version are appended, can I customize it to get rid of it.
3. This is totally unrelated, Is resolvers in build.sbt and plugins.sbt same or different. The reason I ask looks like when I try to sbt reload, resolvers in plugins.sbt is verified, while sbt update, resolver in build.sbt is verified

Any answer or solution is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Plugins are compiled against specific sbt version, which uses specific Scala version. Therefore [`addSbtPlugin`](http://harrah.github.io/xsbt/latest/sxr/Defaults.scala#386289) will add an sbt and Scala version under the hood.
2. You should really not be doing it, because of the first. Your plugin is compiled against a specific version of Scala and sbt, and therefore this values are appended.
3. Sbt [is recursive](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Getting-Started/Full-Def.html), and resolvers defined in `build.sbt` are defined for building your project, and resolvers in `project/plugins.sbt` are used for building your project's build definition.